# doesn't display build in apple store using xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, build, xcode8, application-loader

I am last 3 to 5 day upload try...
I upload build time itune connect display processing message after build complete done that check itune connect doesn't display build version and processing message.

[image]

more than time upload build(diff build version) using archive window and application loader but itunes connect doesn't display build. upload message is display done.

> New Build Upload Project v1.1 and build v 1.1.1
>
> Screen 1
>   [image]
>
> Screen 2
>   [image]
>
> Screen 3
>   [image]

Comment: what is your version and build number exactely that is uploaded on app store?

Comment: v1.1 and build v1.0,1.1,... and today 1.1.0 above screen shot today and check build v 1.1.0 and project 1.1

Comment: Hope you have already a binary in the app store for your app. In the iTunes click the +[Build] button in your app detail page and check whether the uploaded binary is ready to add

Comment: build after doesn't display(+) symbol and check activity->all build doesn't display all build for version 1.1.

Comment: what you want exactly, you want to increase the version number or build number?

Comment: yes, I already 1.0 live but 1.1 build doesn't upload display.

Comment: i have already face this problem you keep the build number is simply 1 or 2  dont use the (1.0,1.1.1,1.0.1)  and upload again its uploaded successfully.

Comment: keep the version number is same 1.1 and change the build number is 1 and uploaded no issue will come.

Comment: no issue, i send screenshot ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Solve my question:

[image]

I add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in plist file because i use photo library.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Photo Library Access Warning</string>
```

> iTunes connect send build invalid reason to apple account mail id. I check my mail id after set above code because I use PhotoLibraryUsageDescription that you are check your mail account.

Answer (score -1):

In New XCode we have to add properties in plist for particular Library Usage [image]